# Strongly-typed dataset as datasource of crystal report

Tags: .net, crystal-reports

I have a strongly-typed dataset with 3 tables. I want to show all of  these 3 tables data on a crystal report. How to set crystal report's datasource to this dataset's tables?

Please please help

Regards
skpaul

Comment: Do you know how to set the data source of the report to a normal data set? Do the same with your typed one...

Comment: the following code does not work:  cr.SetDataSource(Me.dsBatchSheetDetails.Tables("BatchDetails"))
                ' cr.SetDataSource(Me.dsBatchSheetDetails.Tables("PackDetails"))
                ' cr.SetDataSource(Me.dsBatchSheetDetails.Tables("RawDetails"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one datasource.  If the tables are related then you'll need to join them together, or if they are not related then you'll have to use subreports.

Is this information coming from a database?  If it is, I would suggest not using datasets at all and just setting the report to look to the database itself for data.  That will save you a lot of coding and be much easier to maintain.  If that's a possibility for you but you don't know how let me know and I'll provide more info.

Comment: And you can obviously use subreports even if they are related if it's difficult for you to join them.

Comment: @SKPaul What kind of report are you trying to make (i.e. what would you title it) or are you just trying to show the raw data for each table?

Comment: Dear Brandon, Thank you . Imm using access database with "application.startuppath" for the database location. becase it's directoy may be different in clients PC. So i am using strongly typed dataset for reporting. In my dataset, i have 3 tables. For example, a table for customer details, a table for his all orders and a table for his all returns. I want to show these 3 tables data in crystal report.  These tables are related with primary-foreign key. Please help me what technique should i use for this purpose? Can i use  "CrystalReport.SetDataSource(Me.dsDataSet) ?

Comment: do you need to see my source code for better suggesstion? If so, how can i send to you?

Comment: Well it doesn't sound like your source code is the problem so much as your approach.  Are you trying to create a report that takes data from each of these tables and puts it together in a useful manner or are you just trying to show the tables separately (but on the same report)?

Comment: just trying to show the tables separately on the same report. I am collecting data from database, then processing it, then filling datatables in dataset, then trying to send (?) the datatables to crystal report

Comment: Well, the easiest solution would be to show three separate reports instead of trying to do everything on one.  But if that's not an option, then you will have to use subreports.  How to do that is beyond what I am able to explain in a text box here, but you should be able to use google to find the information you need.  Just make sure each subreport is in a different section of the report so that it seperates them properly (unless there are not many columns and you can display them side by side).  You can create new sections if you need, but again I will leave it to google to show you how.

Comment: I know how to create subreports. Can you tell me something more about "Hide (drill-down ok)" and "suppress(no drill-down)" ?

Comment: It allows you to group data in CR but hide the details so that only the group header/footer show up.  But if drill-down is okay then the user can still click on it to unhide the detail section for whichever group they want to see.  Drilling down in CR opens a new page though... I really don't like the way they do drill down and I don't use it.

Comment: I've found another solution to set multiple datasource. here it is-  CR.Database.Tables("tbl").SetDataSource(tblRawItems)

Comment: @SKPaul Yes, but from what you said it sounds like you aren't joining the info from the different tables together.  If you set multiple tables like that you will also need to tell CR what their relation to one another is or it will probably not work as expected.